# How to get direction between two dropped markers using Google API and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get path between two dropped markers by user , i did before using two input fields but now am trying to get direction between two dropped markers by the user. the two markers will be dropped randomly by the user

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <label>Location A: </label>
        <label id="start" ></label>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <label>Location B :</label>
        <label id="end" ></label>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">

        <button onclick="javascript:calculateRoute()" type="button" style="width: 150px">Calculate Distance</button>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label style="color: red; font-weight: bold" id="lblDistance"></label>
    </div>

    <div style="float: left; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: -3px;">

        <button type="button" id="pathbtn" style="width: 115px">Shortest Path</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function initialize() {


var long = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Langitud").value);
var lat = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Latitud").value);
var zoomMap = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Zoom").value)
var disableDefaultUIMap = document.getElementById("disableDefaultUI").checked;
var scrollwheelMap = document.getElementById("scrollwheel").checked;
var draggableMap = document.getElementById("draggable").checked;
var maxZoomMap = parseInt(document.getElementById("maxZoom").value);
var minZoomMap = parseInt(document.getElementById("minZoom").value);
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(long, lat);
var maptype = parseInt(document.getElementById("MapTypeSelect").value)
var mapTypeIdMap;
switch (maptype)
{
    case 1:
        mapTypeIdMap = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP;
        break;
    case 2:
        mapTypeIdMap = google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE;
        break;
    case 3:
        mapTypeIdMap = google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID;
        break;
    case 4:
        mapTypeIdMap = google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN;
        break;
}



var mapProp = {
    center: myCenter,
    zoom: zoomMap,
    mapTypeId: mapTypeIdMap,
    disableDefaultUI: disableDefaultUIMap,
    scrollwheel: scrollwheelMap,
    draggable: draggableMap,
    maxZoom: maxZoomMap,
    minZoom: minZoomMap


};

var iconMarker =  document.getElementById("sc").innerHTML;

var conte = document.getElementById("conte").value;

var draggableMarker = document.getElementById("draggableMarker").checked;

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapProp);



var listenerHandle = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousedown', function (e) {

    var latLng = e.latLng;

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        icon: image

    });

    //// to get data about mouse position
    //mMoveHandler = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function (e) {
    marker.setPosition(e.latLng);
    //});


    //google.maps.event.removeListener(listenerHandle);


    document.getElementById("looo").innerHTML = "Lattitude: " + e.latLng.lat() + '  <br/>   ' + "Longitude: " + e.latLng.lng();
});


//--------------------
var image = {
    url: iconMarker,
    // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels high.
    size: new google.maps.Size(30, 32),
    //// The origin for this image is (0, 0).
    //origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    //// The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at (0, 32).
    //anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
};



var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter,
    map: map,
    draggable: draggableMarker,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
    icon: image


});



var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({


    content: conte,
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);

});
infowindow.open(map, marker);
marker.setMap(map);


document.getElementById("cen").innerHTML = " new google.maps.LatLng( " + long + " , " + lat + " )";
document.getElementById("zoo").innerHTML = " " + zoomMap;
document.getElementById("dis").innerHTML = " " + disableDefaultUIMap;
document.getElementById("swh").innerHTML = " " + scrollwheelMap;
document.getElementById("drag").innerHTML =" "+ draggableMap;
document.getElementById("maxzom").innerHTML = " " + maxZoomMap;
document.getElementById("minzom").innerHTML =" "+ minZoomMap;
document.getElementById("pos").innerHTML = " new google.maps.LatLng( " + long + " , " + lat + " )";
document.getElementById("dra").innerHTML =" "+ draggableMarker;
document.getElementById("contet").innerHTML = " " + conte;
document.getElementById("mapt").innerHTML = " google.maps.MapTypeId." + mapTypeIdMap.toUpperCase();
```

}

Comment: Please provide some code examples of what you have tried.

Comment: i used <input type="Text" id="start"/> <input type="Text" id="end"/> i enter LatLng and its working, now i need to place two markers on the map randomly and compute distance between them.

Answer (score 0):

The google maps directions API requires 3 parameters:

`origin` - Either a latitute/longiture or a plain text name for the departure point

`destination` - Either a latitute/longiture or a plain text name for the arrival point

and your API key of course

To use the dropped markers on the map, you can get their coordinates by using these functions on each of the marker objects:

```
var lat = Marker.getPosition().lat();
var lng = Marker.getPosition().lng();
```

And simply pass the coordinates on an new asynchronous API call:

```
var target = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?orgin='
+originMarkerCoords+'&destination='
+destinationMarkerCoords+'&key='+apiKey;
```

Ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you but i got their coordinates , what am asking is how to distinguish between the two markers

Comment: You don't have the two markers stored in a variable yet?

Comment: the markers will be placed by the user when he click on the map marker.setPosition(e.latLng);